# Google cloud - pub/sub - write to Bigquery with metadata - missing fields

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to enable the Dead letter topic by creating a new topic, called `dl_topic`, and a subscription to this topic called `dl_subs`. For the `dl_subs` subscription, I'm enabling the `Write to BigQuery` option, so I will have the data saved. I would like also to forward metadata of the topic to BQ. If I select the `Write metadata` option, Google suggests also adding a few other fields in the BQ.

```
google_bigquery_table
message_id
publish_time
data
attributes
```

I'm doing this in Terraform. Question is:

- in which block do I need to add these fields? is it in the `bigquery_config` block in TF?
- how do I add the above fields in BQ via Terraform?

also, after the dead_letter topic receives a message and is pushed to BigQuery, how do I replay the message (from BQ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From terraform and GCP documentation it seems you need these additional column in your BigQuery Table.

Terraform Doc
[image]

GCP Doc
[image]

So these additional field will go in BQ schema where you are creating BQ Table and in your terraform code add write_metadata = true.

Comment: thanks! I created tables in BQ and successfully enabled Dead Letter for a subscription.

Comment: Thanks for letting know, you can mark answer to close thread